# Ubuntu 16.04 (on dual boot with Win 10) is not connecting to the wifi

Tags: dual-boot, wireless

I am an Ubuntu novice. I dual booted Ubuntu 16.04 with my Win 10 HP Pavilion X-360 laptop. Whatever I try, I cannot get the Ubuntu to connect to wifi. I have been able to use an external internet dongle, but wifi is just not connecting. Win 10 is connecting fine. Please help!

Was offline for months, that's why the delay in replying. Please help!
Sharing the output:

lspci -knn | grep Net -A3
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:b723]
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [103c:804c]
    Kernel modules: wl, rtl8723be

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3` terminal command.

Comment: you are just facing problem with your wifi driver, as of external dongle; when you attach it via USB system will identify it's driver and install it.